# output of predict in Tensorflow.js always show first example

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I recently learning an image classifier using TensorFlow js in the browser, I made a simple image classification that can identify an image of Giorno and Jotaro, but when predicting a new image, the result always shows the first example(Jotaro) which I added, I'm trying to check the second function which added second example(Giorno), It just fine in console, and running well, this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Giorno and Jotaro Classifier</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/knn-classifier"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test Image</h1>
<img id="predict" src="anime/test_giorno.jpg" alt="" width="300">
</body>
</html>
<script>

const initScript = async function(){
const ClassifierKNN = knnClassifier.create();
const mobileneModule = await mobilenet.load();


for(let i=1; i<=3;i++){
    const im = new Image(300,300);
    im.src = 'anime/jotaro/'+i+'.jpg';
    im.onload = ()=>{
        let trainingImageJotaro = tf.browser.fromPixels(im);
        let predJotaro = mobileneModule.infer(trainingImageJotaro,'conv_preds');
        if(i)
        ClassifierKNN.addExample(predJotaro,"Jotaro");
    }
    im.onload();
}

for(let i=1; i<=3;i++){
    const im2 = new Image(300,300);
    im2.src = 'anime/giorno/'+i+'.jpg';
    im2.onload = ()=>{
        let trainingImageGiorno = tf.browser.fromPixels(im2);
        let predGiorno = mobileneModule.infer(trainingImageGiorno,'conv_preds');
        ClassifierKNN.addExample(predGiorno,"Giorno");
    }
    im2.onload();
}


let imgX = document.getElementById('predict');
const tensorX = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgX);
const logitsX = mobileneModule.infer(tensorX,'conv_preds');
let result = await ClassifierKNN.predictClass(logitsX);
console.log('outout:');
console.log(result);

}
initScript();

</script>
```

the result of the script is always jotaro, but when I switch the loop position like this:

```
for(let i=1; i<=3;i++){
const im2 = new Image(300,300);
im2.src = 'anime/giorno/'+i+'.jpg';
im2.onload = ()=>{
    let trainingImageGiorno = tf.browser.fromPixels(im2);
    let predGiorno = mobileneModule.infer(trainingImageGiorno,'conv_preds');
    ClassifierKNN.addExample(predGiorno,"Giorno");
}
im2.onload();
}

for(let i=1; i<=3;i++){
    const im = new Image(300,300);
    im.src = 'anime/jotaro/'+i+'.jpg';
    im.onload = ()=>{
        let trainingImageJotaro = tf.browser.fromPixels(im);
        let predJotaro = mobileneModule.infer(trainingImageJotaro,'conv_preds');
        if(i)
        ClassifierKNN.addExample(predJotaro,"Jotaro");
    }
    im.onload();
   }
```

the result always Giorno, can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: This problem has been fixed, the problem in the question above occurs because, the second training data is executed after the testing data, therefore the code above only gets 1 label, because the second label has not been executed. and therefore the output label of the predicted image always shows the label of the first training data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @zer0sign, for sharing the solution in comments. For the benefit of community I am providing solution here (answer section)

This problem has been fixed, above issue occurs because, the second training data is executed after the testing data, therefore the code above only gets 1 label, because the second label has not been executed and therefore the output label of the predicted image always shows the label of the first training data.